# Bilinear interpolation implementations in Tensorflow and OpenCV

Tags: numpy, opencv, tensorflow, interpolation

I'm trying to get a handle on [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) as implemented in [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) and [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). My understanding leads me to believe that the grid of interpolation points is positioned differently in the two libraries. This is evidenced by the different results obtained on a sample matrix:

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, cv2
a = np.arange(9, dtype=np.float32).reshape(3, 3)
cv2.resize(a, (2, 2))
```

outputs

```
array([[1. , 2.5],
       [5.5, 7. ]], dtype=float32)
```

while

```
tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.image.resize_images(a[None, :, :, None], (2, 2)).eval()[0, :, :, 0]
```

outputs

```
array([[0. , 1.5],
       [4.5, 6. ]], dtype=float32)
```

Is that diagnosis correct? If so, what are the schemes for laying down interpolation points in tensorflow and OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

Commonly (in OpenCV, Matlab, scipy, etc.), pixels are assumed to cover unit areas and what is aligned are the very corners of the top-left and bottom-right pixels. Sampling interval changes to `old_size / new_size`.

In Tensorflow, there are two brand new schemes, neither of which matches the one above.

For `align_corners=True`, the corner pixel *centers* are aligned with new sampling interval of `(old_size - 1) / (new_size - 1)` in-between.
For `align_corners=False`, only the top-left pixel *centers* are aligned and the rest is sampled with interval `old_size / new_size`.

Comment: Is that going to hamper the performance if we predict using tensorflow pre processing while trained using OpenCV preprocessing ?